# Detecting bad input for `boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima()`

Tags: c++, boost

[This](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/brent_minima.html) documentation page of `boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima` says about its first argument:

> The function to minimise: a function object (or C++ lambda) ... with no maxima occurring in that interval.

But what happens if this is not the case? (After all, this condition is rather difficult to pre-ensure, especially since the function is usually expensive to evaluate at many points.) Best would be to detect violations to this condition on  the fly.

If this condition is violated, does boost throw an exception, or does it exhibit undefined behavior?

A workaround I am thinking of is to build the checking into the lambda ("function to minimize"), by capturing and maintaining a `std::map<double,double>` holding all the points that  have been evaluated, and comparing each new evaluation with its nearest neighbor in each direction, to check whether there may be a local maximum. But I don't want to do all that if it isn't necessary.

Comment: I deleted the answer, because actually I didnt like it at all and it was somehow drowned in discussion. I would suggest you do look at the source and if the `boost` implementation isnt doing what you expect you could write your own.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thank you; I appreciated the discussion. That is exactly what I decided to do. (And you are right about `boost::math::tools::brent_find_minima` not doing any such checking.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for this to be done. If you read Corless's *A Graduate Introduction to Numerical Methods*, you'll read a very interesting point: All numerically defined functions are discontinuous halfway between representables, and have zero derivatives between representables. Basically they can be thought of as a sum of Heaviside functions.

So *none* of them are differentiable in the mathematical sense. Ok, maybe you think this is a bit unfair-the scale should be zoomed out. But how much? We know that `|x-1|` isn't differentiable at `x=1`, but how could a computer tell that? How does it know that there isn't some locally smooth mollifier that makes it differentiable between `x=1-eps` and `x=1+eps`? I don't think there's a good answer to this question.

One of the most difficult problems in this class arises in quadrature. Some of these methods work fast when the complex extension of the function has poles far from the real axis. Try to numerically determine *that*.

Function spaces are impossible to determine numerically. Users just have to get it right.

Comment: I agree on smoothness. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in the question, but I was thinking only of unimodality ("with no maxima occuring in that interval"). The search works by successively narrowing down a bracket around the presumed minimum. If at some point the algorithm encounters a value within the bracket that is higher than the bracket's end-points, then the condition is clearly violated.

Comment: Smoothness is harder than maxima determination, but if you can't guarantee smoothness then maxima can be detected only by exhaustive search.